# Googlesheet - How to populate cells from a text

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have for example this content in B8 : "1/2/4.5/8/9.2"
I would like to break this line at each "/" and put the value in neighbour cells. Like on this example :

[image]

I assume a ARRAYFORMULA should be use, but I can't find a way to do that... Someone has an idea ?
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say if cell B8 has the said value, use:

```
=SPLIT(B8,"/")
```

if your locale supports semicolon convention then it would be:

```
=SPLIT(B8;"/")
```

Comment: Thank's ! I entered into a comlicated world with my Arrayformula solution

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the column, you can use Data -> Split text to columns option. Then you can use the custom separator as /.